# Reading JSON Object returned from Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm writing a simple Django application that returns a JSON Object,

Django view return string

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(results),mimetype='application/json')
```

JSON:

```
{'table1':{'col1':'a','col2':'b'}
,'table2':{'col1':'c','col2':'d'}}
```

Javascript call

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url:"/validate/",
    data:{'fieldvalue':fieldvalue,'fieldname':fieldname,'tablename':tablename},
    context:this,
    success:function(response){
        $.each(response,function(k,v){
            console.log("Value of k = " + k)
            console.log("Value of v = " + v.col1)
        })
```

Im able to successfully read the JSON Object but when I refer directly like response.table1.col1, it does not work properly...What is the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response is not valid JSON.

According to http://json.org only " is valid.

Try validating you JSON on http://jsonlint.com/
And then try replacing ' with " and try again.

```
{"table1":{"col1":"a","col2":"b"}
,"table2":{"col1":"c","col2":"d"}}
```

I created a working sample for you here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/2kZTKAzqG9qfQLxXgn8s

Only thing change is the qoutes in the json. (and added some extra console.log )